# How to add meta_data while creating a product under a category by using rest api woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the default WooCommerce rest API to create a product. Now I need to extend the product creation endpoint to add `meta_data` and `multiple categories` to a product while creating:

> POST /wp-json/wc/v3/products

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product

```
$data = array(
    'name'              => $request->post( 'name' ),
    'description'       => $request->post( 'description' ),
    'categories[0][id]' => $request->post( 'category' ),
    'regular_price'     => $request->post( 'price' ),
    'meta_data'         => [
        'key'   => 'this is key of meta',
        'value' => 'this is value of meta'
    ]
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $action_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => $action_method,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( wordpress_api_key . ':' . api_secret )
    ),
) );

$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

echo $response;
```

In the response, I'm getting an error `Array to string conversion`.

When I use `json_encode( $data )` then no data is saved, it returns default data for product.